# output and misunderstanding in C++

Tags: c++, increment, custom-data-type

I want to know why the output is (1), and why In the second assignment to variable b, the expression (i+=2) does not get evaluated. finally how does this program execute step by step?
I am still a beginner.

`

```
int i = 0;
bool t = true;
bool f = false,
    b;

b = (t && ((i++) == 0));
b = (f && (i += 2 > 0));

cout << i << endl;
```

`

Comment: Look up "short-circuit evaluation". Since the first operand of `&&` is false, there's no need to evaluate the second one.

Comment: Because it is short circuited - the right part of the && does not need to be avaluated because the left is already false and therefore the entire thing is false.

Comment: more precisely c and c++ *guarantee* that the second part is not evaluated, same is true for `||` if the first expression evaluates to `true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `&&` operator short-circuits and `f` is `false`, `1 += 2` is not being evaluated.

Since the entire expression can only be `true` if *both* operands to `&&` are `true`, there is no need to evaluate `(i += 2 > 0)` to determine that the value of the entire expression is `false`. Given the lack of *need* to evaluate the second operand in this scenario, many programming languages guarantee that it will not be, including C and C++.

Be careful about using operands with side-effects in boolean expressions.

Comment: not only is there no need, c and c++ (mosy languages in fact) guarantee that the second one is not evaluated

Comment: Short-circuit evaluation does not apply to overloaded `&&` operators, though, if I am not mistaken.